# Can I stop and start a windows service from IIS app running under application pool identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an IIS web application that is run under an application pool identity. The app needs to stop and start a windows service. Apart from introducing impersonation into the application for stopping and starting the service, is there any other way I can do this?

Note that I am looking for a solution other than running the application pool under a windows user that has the permission to stop and start the service.

Comment: With having fairly high reputation points, I am actually surprised that you could not do a google search on the following `starting and stopping a windows service programmatically` have you at least tried executing a valid google search..?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question is regarding application pool identities and the connection with windows service and not "Starting and stopping a windows service programmatically". If it was easy as that I would have 'googled' and found the answer by now.

Comment: Your question answers itself - if the app pool identity doesn't have the rights, the site needs to impersonate an account that does.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732742(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Wow, super not helpful MethodMan...  JD did you ever find a good solution for this problem (which I thought you stated very well, thank you).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through your app pool if:

1- Your local and/or domain security policies allow a service to stop/start another service.

2- Your app pool identity has the right to do so.

Granting the app pool identity such a right might be a security issue though.